# Determining the largest missing number in a list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

The argument is a list and I am trying to extract the largest missing number from the list.

I have sorted the list in the function `select`, but I am having a hard time getting the function `select` to return the sorted list. When the list returns from sorting it, I am subtracting the highest and second highest to determine the difference and checking to see if the difference is greater than 1.

Could someone let me know how to return the sorted list from Selected to `LargestGap`?

```
(define (LargestGap L)
  (cond ( (null? L) '() )
 ;       ( car (select L))
        ( (> (- (car(cdr(select L))) (car(select L))) 0) (LargestGap (cdr(select L))))
        (- (car(select L)) 1)))

(define (select L)
   (cond ( (null? L) '() )
         ( else 
           (cons (Largest L (car L))
                      (select (delete L (Largest L (car L))))))))

(define (delete L A)
  (cond ( (null? L) '() )
        ( (= (car L) A) (cdr L))
        (else (cons (car L)(delete (cdr L) A)))))

(define (Largest L A)
  (cond ( (null? L) A)
        ( (> (car L) A) (Largest (cdr L)(car L)))
        (else (Largest (cdr L) A ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly. I guess you want to avoid calling `select` function many times in `LargestGap` function. If this is what your question is then:

Make another function:

```
(define (get-largest-gap L) 
    (LargestGap (select L)))
```

Make function LargestGap such that is accepts sorted list:

```
(define (LargestGap L)
  (cond ( (null? L) '() )
        ( (> (- (cadr L) (car L)) 0) (LargestGap (cdr L)))
        (- (car L) 1)))
```